# Reset and Layout UV is really slow

Tags: uv, baking, vertex-colors

[image]

I have this 3D Voxel sculpture, this was made of thousands of Box objects, but merged into a single object and it has a nice Vertex Color per Box.

Anyhow, I would like to somewhat layout the UV of this mesh and bake it into a single texture.

I know Blender can "Reset UV" but when I tried to arrange the UV into a nice grid, it simply freezes...

I thought I could just do Auto-UV and then bake transfer, but that's also taking a while.

Comment: I mean I tried Pack Islands on UV that is reset, but this is taking too long time. There must be a tool out there that simply lay down each polygon face, in order, and nicely fit the UV square.

Comment: Jimmy I love you nohomo